# Creating a new metric from existing data in a dataframe - merging categories in one column by two continuous columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, aggregate, self-join

Heres an extract from the dataframe I am working with:

```
date         batsmanballs   Batsman      Runs on each ball
2016-03-18          3        Chris              1
2013-02-09         12        Ben                2
2018-01-07          2        Eoin               1
```

The date column represents when a match was played, the batsman balls the number of balls the batsman has faced in an innings
I am trying to create a new feature, the number of balls all batsman have faced over their entire career

Showing this information for a specific batsman is fairly straightforward:

```
df= df.sort_values(by=['date', 'batsmanballs'], ascending=True)
```

How could I display 'carer balls' for every batsman in the database?

I have tried using groupby, but this only shows career balls by each batsman rather than all batsman

Comment: `df.groupby('Batsman')['batsmanballs'].sum()`?

Comment: If you want it as a new column do `df['total_balls'] = df.groupby('Batsman')['batsmanballs'].transform('sum')`

Comment: Great answer, but does not exactly give the intended output, my fault for not articulating clearly in the question. The aim is to display a series of values for the number of balls faced by each batsman over their career, rather than the total number of balls faced